# How to control the connection while uploading to AWS S3?

Tags: networking, backup, amazon-web-services, online-backup, aws-cloud9

Is there a way to control the connection while uploading from my servers to the AWS Storage?
**to be clear**, Azcopy is so powerful to upload to AWS, so most of our bandwidth consumed and this is affecting our DataCenter !!
So is there a command to let Azcopy limit the connection for every transfer (max 100M speed for every server ),
so if I have 3 servers, the consumed bandwidth must be 300M only from the total speed (1000M).

Comment: You might find a better audience for this question on one of SuperUser's sister sites in the Stack Exchange network, such as Server Fault.

Comment: you are right, I will post this question on ServerFault too. Thanks

Comment: Good news, I was lucky to find a simple and quick tool named Gs richcopy360 on the site "Spiceworks", suggested to handle a similar issue, the tool has been installed, tested and it works well as promised, thanks Spiff